# Piping contents of buffer into eshell command

Tags: eshell, pipe

I know `eshell` supports output redirection to buffers

```
cmd > #<buffername>
```

Is there a way to do piping buffer contents into command? I would like to have something like

```
cat #<buffername> | cmd
```

The problem is that `cat` is not a builtin so it doesn't know `emacs` buffers. 
I could always save the buffer `buffername` to a file and then `cat` it but that is not always desired (e.g r-o filesystem)

## In more detail

I am passing from using a terminal emulator with zsh towards using eshell. Often I write scripts that run a command, pipe the output into `grep`,`gawk`, `sed` or whatnot and then pipe the result into another program.

I would like to separate this into steps. I know `eshell` supports output redirection to buffer via

```
cmb > #<buffername>
```

I would then process the contents of `buffername` using powerful `emacs` tools. 
I know then that `eshell` **does not** support input redirection. I read in some manual to use pipes instead.

If I saved the output to a file with `cmb > filename` I could then do

```
cat filename | cmd2
```

but sometimes saving a `buffername` to a file `filename` is impossible or inconvenient. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `M-|` (`shell-command-on-region`).

Within eshell, you can use

```
~ $ (with-current-buffer "*scratch*" (buffer-string)) | nl
     1  ;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
     2  ;; To create a file, visit it with <open> and enter text in its buffer.

~ $
```

Eshell commands are Emacs functions, e.g,.

```el
(defun kitty (buffer)
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (buffer-string)))
```

```
~ $ kitty #<*scratch*> | nl
     1  ;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
     2  ;; To create a file, visit it with <open> and enter text in its buffer.

     3  (defun kitty (buffer)
     4    (with-current-buffer buffer
     5      (buffer-string)))
~ $
```

here is another way to write an eshell command, then you can invoke it via `your-cat` in eshell:

```el
(defun eshell/your-cat (&rest args)
  (if (bufferp (car args))
      (with-current-buffer (car args)
        (buffer-string))
    (apply #'eshell/cat args)))
```

Comment: Just to clarify, could I also make `kitty` a `eshell`-only command be better by defining it as `eshell/kitty`? Also, could you help modify `kitty` to call cat if called with a filename and cat a buffer if called with a buffer name. I will try to do it myself and post it here but I am not good with lisp.

Comment: @GenaU Yes, the Emacs function named `eshell/foo` can be invoked as `foo` in Eshell. You can use `bufferp` to test if the argument is a buffer, if it's not, you can fallback to `eshell/cat`, e.g., `(defun eshell/your-cat (&rest args) (if (bufferp (car args)) (cat-buffer ...) (apply #'eshell/cat args)))`.